# ¿Cómo extraigo links y usuarios de un texto para pasarlos a otra columna?

Tags: pandas, twitter, enlace

Tengo una columna de texto que se ve de esta manera:

```
tweet
1   "¿Tienes dudas sobre #ciberseguridad y no sabes a quién acudir? Desde @INCIBE queremos recordarte que estamos a tu disposición en nuestro teléfono gratuito ☎017. ¡Te ayudaremos!
  https://www.osi.es/es/contacto  pic.twitter.com/uJ3zNQxfda"
2   Hola @ProtoMot, te recomendamos que leas el siguiente artículo de nuestra web y si sigues teniendo dudas puedes llamarnos gratuitamente al 017 la Línea de Ayuda en Ciberseguridad. https://www.osi.es/es/actualidad/blog/2019/04/04/microsoft-te-ha-llamado-sin-haberlo-solicitado …
3   "Hola @Lotharmatao2020, para atender tu consulta de forma personalizada puedes ponerte en contacto con nosotros llamando gratuitamente al 017, la Línea de Ayuda en Ciberseguridad.
 https://www.incibe.es/linea-de-ayuda-en-ciberseguridad …"
N = 400
```

Pero me gustaría obtener de esa columna las menciones y links, de tal modo que la nueva columna me quede de este modo:

```
tweet_mentions
    1    @INCIBE
     https://www.osi.es/es/contacto  pic.twitter.com/uJ3zNQxfda"
    2 @ProtoMot
https://www.osi.es/es/actualidad/blog/2019/04/04/microsoft-te-ha-llamado-sin-haberlo-solicitado …
    3    @Lotharmatao2020
     https://www.incibe.es/linea-de-ayuda-en-ciberseguridad …"
N=400
```

Estaba pensando en crear una función que identifique los @ y https pero no sé que sería lo mejor

Comment: Hola @Daniela Brieva . En StackOverflow es necesario poner el código con lo  que has intentado para que podamos ayudarte. Esto además nos ayuda a ver claramente el problema que tienes. En el caso de que no hayas intentado nada, investiga y trata de hacer algo por tus medios, te puedo sugerir que veas el módulo ```re``` de Python que te ayudará en lo que quieres hacer.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías resolver tu consulta mediante el módulo `re` de python, te dejo un ejemplo:

```
import re

print(re.search("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", myString).group("url"))
```

Espero te sirva !